# Referencing global variables in my main class?

Tags: java

I've come across the need to reference/access global variables from my main class. I am using another class which also involves a thread (for networking stuff). Basically I was wondering if I can do it the following way (I've checked and I don't get any compilation errors):

```
public class One
{
    public static int number;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        number = 5;
        Two two = new Two();
        System.out.println(number);        
    }
}

public class Two
{
    public Two()
    {
        One.number = 10;
    }
}
```

And if so, is that acceptable? Is there a better way (other then normally passing the arguments)?

Thanks for taking the time to read this, sorry if I'm being confusing (tired x.x).

Comment: not much clear.. here I cant find any statement which is passing an argument.

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? Probably not. Is it acceptable? [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) and [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) are at least `final`; I think the smell diminishes (but is not entirely eliminated) if it's `final`. Why do you need a global?

Comment: @bachu `One.number = 10;` assigns a value to the global variable in `One`.

Comment: A couple global variables are ServerSocket and ArrayList objects, I can't have them be final for me to use them.

Comment: @Honor I would suggest you refactor so that those aren't global. You haven't posted any relevant code, and your question was is it possible? I think yes, but what happened when you ran it? Basically, what are you really asking?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I was having a strange bug, and I was completely sure it was caused because of referencing a object in the main class. I spent well around and hour experimenting with it. After I read some responses I found my mistake. But the whole point of posting the thread was because this idea has been on my mind for around half a year now.

Comment: I would recommend avoid using global variables. You can use a `singleton` instead or, if that value never changes, you can use an `Enum`

Comment: The variable definitely will be changing. I'll look into a "singleton", thanks

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do this would to be have it as a private variable and to add accessor and mutator methods to the class containing information, such as:

```
//Accessor
public int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}

//Mutator
public void setNumber(int num)
{
    number = num;
}
```

I suppose you did say "other than passing the arguments", but this would be the acceptable way to do this as you also asked. In this way, you can prevent outside classes from manipulating the data incorrectly, among other things.

Comment: So like, One.setNumber(10); ?

Comment: @Honor Yes, that is correct. However, note that to use it in this way the setNumber method must be made static.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to access it but if you are using threading them make sure that multiple threads are not writting at the same time on that variable. In such cases you can use synchronize block for write operation, or you can use locking mechanism.
There is also one suggestion on this. make that variable private and use getter and setter to access it to limit the visibility and misuse.